# Celery not connecting to Redis Broker (Django)

Tags: django, redis, celery

This is my first time using Celery and redis so there's probably something obvious that I'm not inferring from the documentation and searching through others' questions on here. Whenever I try to run a worker my connection keeps timing out with:

```
ResponseError: unknown command 'WATCH'
[2013-06-12 18:25:23,059: ERROR/MainProcess] consumer: Connection to broker lost. Trying    to re-establish the connection...
```

here's my requirements.txt

```
South==0.7.6
amqp==1.0.11
anyjson==0.3.3
billiard==2.7.3.28
boto==2.9.4
celery==3.0.19
celery-with-redis==3.0
dj-database-url==0.2.1
django-admin-bootstrapped==0.3.2
django-celery==3.0.17
django-jsonfield==0.9.4
django-stripe-payments==2.0b20
mimeparse==0.1.3
oauthlib==0.4.0
paramiko==1.10.1
psycopg2==2.5
pycrypto==2.6
python-dateutil==2.1
python-openid==2.2.5
pytz==2013b
redis==2.7.5
requests==1.2.0
requests-oauthlib==0.3.1
six==1.3.0
stripe==1.7.9
wsgiref==0.1.2
```

settings.py

```
import djcelery
djcelery.setup_loader()

INSTALLED_APPS = (
...
'djcelery',
...
)

CACHES = {
    "default": {
        "BACKEND": "redis_cache.cache.RedisCache",
        "LOCATION": "127.0.0.1:6379:1",
        "OPTIONS": {
        "CLIENT_CLASS": "redis_cache.client.DefaultClient",
        }
    }
}

BROKER_URL = 'redis://localhost:6379/0'
```

when I start my redis server and run

```
./manage.py celeryd -B
```

My connect just keeps timing out with:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/worker/consumer.py", line 395, in start
self.consume_messages()
File "/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/worker/consumer.py", line 407, in    consume_messages
with self.hub as hub:
File "/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/worker/hub.py", line 198, in __enter__
self.init()
File "/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/worker/hub.py", line 146, in init
callback(self)
File "/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/worker/consumer.py", line 401, in on_poll_init
self.connection.transport.on_poll_init(hub.poller)
File "/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kombu/transport/redis.py", line 749, in on_poll_init
self.cycle.on_poll_init(poller)
File "/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kombu/transport/redis.py", line 266, in on_poll_init
num=channel.unacked_restore_limit,
File "/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kombu/transport/redis.py", line 159, in restore_visible
self.restore_by_tag(tag, client)
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/contextlib.py", line 35, in __exit__
self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
File "/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kombu/transport/redis.py", line 94, in Mutex
pipe.watch(name)
File "/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/redis/client.py", line 1941, in watch
return self.execute_command('WATCH', *names)
File "/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/redis/client.py", line 1760, in execute_command
return self.immediate_execute_command(*args, **kwargs)
File "/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/redis/client.py", line 1779, in immediate_execute_command
return self.parse_response(conn, command_name, **options)
File "/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/redis/client.py", line 1883, in parse_response
self, connection, command_name, **options)
File "/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/redis/client.py", line 388, in parse_response
response = connection.read_response()
File "/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/redis/connection.py", line 309, in read_response
raise response
ResponseError: unknown command 'WATCH'
[2013-06-12 18:25:23,059: ERROR/MainProcess] consumer: Connection to broker lost. Trying to re-establish the connection...
```

redis:

```
[1197] 12 Jun 18:50:09 * Server started, Redis version 1.3.14
[1197] 12 Jun 18:50:09 * DB loaded from disk: 0 seconds
[1197] 12 Jun 18:50:09 * The server is now ready to accept connections on port 6379
[1197] 12 Jun 18:50:09 - Accepted 127.0.0.1:53061
[1197] 12 Jun 18:50:09 - DB 0: 2 keys (0 volatile) in 4 slots HT.
[1197] 12 Jun 18:50:09 - 1 clients connected (0 slaves), 1076976 bytes in use
[1197] 12 Jun 18:50:09 - Accepted 127.0.0.1:53062
[1197] 12 Jun 18:50:09 - Accepted 127.0.0.1:53063
[1197] 12 Jun 18:50:09 - Client closed connection
[1197] 12 Jun 18:50:09 - Accepted 127.0.0.1:53064
[1197] 12 Jun 18:50:09 - Client closed connection
[1197] 12 Jun 18:50:09 - Accepted 127.0.0.1:53065
[1197] 12 Jun 18:50:09 - Client closed connection
[1197] 12 Jun 18:50:09 - Accepted 127.0.0.1:53066
[1197] 12 Jun 18:50:09 - Client closed connection
etc etc.
```

Any guidance for where I should be looking or what possible culprits are? thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your Redis server is too old (1.3.14) to be used with Celery. From this error you can see Celery is trying to use the [`WATCH` command](http://redis.io/commands/watch) which was introduced in Redis 2.2.